# How to query a SQL Server table with Months Range

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that have data store in this format, I want to extract data from March 2014 to Feburary 2015, how can I achieve this, please?

```
ID    Months    Years   fd1 fd2 fd3 fd4
-------------------------------------------
1    january    2014    1   2   3   8
2    february   2014    2   2   2   5
3    march      2014    2   5   3   5
4    april      2014    3   4   2   2
5    may        2014    4   1   3   2
6    june       2014    1   1   2   2
7    july       2014    2   3   3   4
8    august     2014    5   6   2   5
9    september  2014    12  2   5   6
10   october    2014    11  1   5   3
11   november   2014    1   5   5   7
12   december   2014    3   8   5   8
13   january    2015    4   1   8   1   
14   february   2015    5   9   8   4
15   march      2015    6   2   2   5   
16   april      2015    6   5   20  2   
17   may        2015    6   2   2   2   
18   june       2015    9   5   2   2    
19   july       2015    10  6   2   2    
20   august     2015    12  3   2   5   
21   september  2015    55  2   2   2
22   october    2015    1   1   2   5
23   november   2015    3   5   5   2
24   december   2015    2   5   5   5
```

Comment: this is answered by the fundamentals of the `where`, `and` and `or` sql clauses...very easy to learn and TRY

Comment: Survey, please fill: I've tried the query .... but I faced the problem ... . During my research, I found out, that ...., but I have a problem to fully understand or apply the knowledge. Please direct me in the right direction. So far, I know, that the solution with ... or with ... or the one with ... don't work for me because ....

Comment: You should never store data with name of the month + year. You should have a date field with the date as the first of the month.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTableName
WHERE (MONTH(Months+ ' 1 2014') IN (1,2) AND Years = 2015) OR (MONTH(Months+ ' 1 2014') > 2 AND Years = 2014)
```

Comment: thanks Jenson and Kunal, Jenson i want you to know that before posting my challenges in this forum i have tried on my own. Kunal you have Months do i put the month range i am searching for, because sql 2008 R2 is giving error "The month function requires 1 argument(s)" what can do?

Comment: Sorry for a typo because I was typing from phone. Here u go. Corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

First you should convert `Years` and `Months` columns to a `DATE` field(Here named as `Dates`).

Then compare the wanted date on `Dates` column.

```
WITH cte(ID, Months, Years, fd1, fd2, fd3, fd4, Dates)
AS
(
    SELECT  ID, Months, Years, fd1, fd2, fd3, fd4, CAST(CAST(Years AS NVARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(Months AS NVARCHAR) AS DATE)
    FROM    tblYearMonth
)

SELECT  *
FROM    cte
WHERE   Dates >= '2014 March' AND Dates <= '2015 February'
ORDER   BY Dates
```